# Azure Web App - Web Service best practice for running exe

Tags: c#, azure, memory-management, exe, process.start

I'm facing a problem with a Web Service that uses a .exe file to produce his response.

Actually the service is working with a simple "Process.Start" of the .exe file with the correct parameters.

Everything works smoothly but I have this "problem". Being one of the parameters a HUGE file of 1GB the system takes 15secs to load this file EVERY request in memory.

This file is ALWAYS the same, open in read only.

How can I let the system know to maintain it in memory?

I can basically follow different approaches:

- Find a way to say to the system "keep this file in RAM"
- Embed the .exe in something like "loop for input" (and use always the same process)
- Publish the exe as a Continuosly running Azure Web Job

Before trying out every approach on my own, what is the best approach and why?

Thanks in advance

Comment: IMHO not easy to help you. Not sure about your architecture... Do you confirm that asp.net start a EXE with a process.start() and waits for completion? Potentially could you have more than one request at a time? I mean in parallel.

Comment: ASP.NET starts an .EXE file with the "huge file" as parameter. The problem is that the garbage collector "cleans" the huge file from the memory. If I find a way to reuse it the process is basically takes only 20ms

Comment: On app start, copy the huge ass file to `d:\local\temp`, and reference from there -- that's local storage and is many times faster than the networked storage your Web App reads from (`d:\home\site\wwwroot`). Beware `d:\local` is temporary storage and gets wiped when app restarts or worker dies.

Comment: @ZibaLeah it's not the .NET garbage collector that removes the file from memory. When asp.net starts an external process with Process.Start, the operating system creates a new process and, at exit, it will clean up all the resources.  If you can modify the .exe, consider to convert it to a standard Windows Service (not a so easy  task...). Another solution could be to run the .exe in a dedicated Virtual Machine. Doing that, the VM will likely cache the big file and starts the exe faster. There would be other approaches but they really depend on what you can do with the existing .exe

Comment: @evilSnobu I tried but the time it takes to take the file in RAM is almost the same! AVG 15 sec in both part of the disk!

Comment: Then it's not network latency, it's something else. Show some code. What's that binary doing? Can you wrap it and expose it as a service (raw TCP) 
 or Web API?